# How to code categorial variables as numeric in R

Tags: r

I am analysing the CHFLS data set in R which is found in the library HSAUR2. I want to fit a linear model to this data to find out the effect of other variables on the variable R_happy; R_happy has been coded so that a 1 is denoted for "Very happy" and 0 otherwise. I am just wondering how I code the rest of the variables, for example, R_region as numeric so I can use dummy variables and fit a linear model? I have tried using as.numeric but it hasn't worked. My code is as follows:

Load necessary library

```
library("HSAUR2") #Load necessary library
data(CHFLS,package="HSAUR2") #Load the Chinese Health and Family Life Survey data

View(CHFLS) #Read details about the data, including the covariates.
help("CHFLS")

summary(CHFLS) #Produce a summary of the data

#Pie chart showing womens self reported happiness
slices <- c(280, 1254)
lbls <- c("Very happy (18.25%)", "Otherwise(81.75%)")
pie(slices, labels=lbls)

#Define the variable of interest to be y which is 1 when
#"Very happy" (or greater) and 0 otherwise
y<-(CHFLS$R_happy>="Very happy")

# Append y onto the data and call the new data CHFLSnew
CHFLSnew<-cbind(CHFLS,y)

# Ensure that any categorical variables are coded as factors.
CHFLSnew$y<-as.factor(CHFLSnew$y)

##Append y as factor onto CHFLSnew
CHFLSnew<-cbind(CHFLS,y)
```

Comment: If the variable is conceptually categorical, leave it as factor. R will handle everything for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Save us some trouble:  what class is `R_region` ?  And what happens when you try `as.numeric` ?  For example, if it's a `factor`, you need to use `as.numeric(as.character( ))`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : as.numeric works with factors even without 'as.character' conversion. The output is identical.

Comment: @mso - that's only true when the factor "names" coincidentally happen to be the same as their index valuc in the factor order.  Try it with , e.g.,  `foo <- as.factor((1:10)/10)`

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to convert a `factor` to `numeric`:

```
f <- factor(1:10)
f
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

n <- as.numeric(levels(f)[f])
n
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```